# Adding point data from text file when coordinates are in OSGB36

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, ordnance-survey

I have a text file in which coordinates are in the OSGB36 National Grid reference system used in Great Britain, so the coordinates are not in longitude and latitude (e.g. coordinates look like this: SD481731, and are only in one column).
I would like to display these points in QGIS 2.4.0.
However, when adding a delimited text layer, it is mandatory to specify the X and the Y fields.

Can I circumvent this and display OSGB36 coordinates imported directly from one column in a text file?

Comment: set your crs to osgb36 add the x,y points in then change your coordinate system to wgs84 and export for lat/lng.

Answer (score 1):

Okay I see **SD481731** needs to be separated into Eastings and Northings

which is 
X=348100&Y=473100

http://www.nearby.org.uk/coord.cgi?p=SD481731&f=full

For Lat/LNG
https://www.google.co.uk/maps/place/54%C2%B009%2703.9%22N+2%C2%B047%2746.1%22W/@54.1636496,-2.7901201,13z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x0:0x0

You will need to do this to all your OS Grid References
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordnance_Survey_National_Grid

Comment: Just building on this answer there are various online tools for batch converting national grid references to lat-long. This is one which allows you to paste in your data table and produces a lat-long output table: http://gridreferencefinder.com/batchConvert/batchConvert.php

Answer (score 1):

What you have are Ordnance Survey National Grid References. To batch convert these to Ordnance Survey Coordinates I'd suggest you have a look at NG Converter, see:
  http://digimap.edina.ac.uk/webhelp/os/data_information/os_data_issues/ng_converter.htm